# Клик по части прямоугольника

Tags: javascript

Нужно определить по какой именно части прямоугольника кликнул пользователь ( грубо говоря, по какому именно треугольнику )

[image: для примера]

Что мы имеем:

- x, y - координаты клика
- высота, ширина изображения

[решение](http://canvas.alexwindhope.com/t/), отдельное спасибо [[@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov).

Comment: Вам обязательно нужно делить по диагоналям?

Comment: @istem, к сожалению да :)

Comment: Советую взглянуть в сторону уравнений прямой и смотреть на координаты нажатия относительно двух прямых.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x,y - координаты.
w,h - ширина,высота.
1,2,3,4 - номера треугольников начиная с верхнего, дальше по часовой стрелке.

y - x * h / w < 0?"1 или 2":"3 или 4";// относительно главной диагонали
y - (h - x * h / w) < 0?"1 или 4":"2 или 3";//относительно побочной диагонали
```

принадлежность линиям соответственно проверка на равенство нулю этих выражений.

Comment: [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/uZdMN/)

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте применить конструкции из тегов <map> и <area> с соответствующими обработчиками.

Comment: @istem, да, порой, хорошее решение, но, к сожалению, не в моем случае :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, почему? Обьясните подробнее, может вы умалчиваете какой-то важный факт из условия :)

Comment: @Crasher эм, ну это пересечение прямоугольной изометрии, в моем реально use case - это не картинка

Comment: Если работает onclick, тогда нужно смотреть в сторону поворота координатной сетки.

Comment: @istem - представьте себе - 1к таких прямоугольников и обновление map для любого их смещения, тогда уж лучше тупо циклом по всем треугольникам - входит, не входит.

Comment: Прошу прощения за повторение. Onclick (это означает, что клик был именно по нужному элементу), далее поворачиваете систему координат параметризируя соответственно width и height вашего прямоугольника. Остаётся определить в какой четверти был клик по +-X и +-Y. Как-то так. Если честно, мне лень смотреть про повороты и преобразования. Поэтому не смогу помочь с конкретным примером. Возможно завтра...

Comment: @istem - если честно, то преобразования и повороты тут не уместны

Comment: В таком случае - давайте подробности.